# How to dynamically change the Appearance of a control in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

How can I dynamically change the appearance of b? Strangely it works for the Enabled state but not for the Appearance.

Thanks.

```
Manipulate[
  bAppearance = If[a > 1, "Open", "Closed"]; 
  bEnabled = If[a > 2, False, True];
  Plot[Sin[a x + b], 
  {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10, Appearance -> Dynamic@bAppearance}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way around it -- make the `Manipulator` dynamic:

```
Manipulate[
 bAppearance = If[a > 1, "Open", "Closed"];
 bEnabled = If[a > 2, False, True];
 Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],
 {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10, Dynamic@Manipulator[##, Appearance -> bAppearance] &}]
```

The `Manipulator` is recreated when `bAppearance` changes.  It won't be recreated when `b` changes because `b` will be wrapped in `Dynamic` when the control is created.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the appearance of most controls, but the Manipulator Control has something in it that prevents its dynamic behavior (a bug or a feature ?).

Look (with a slider):

```
Manipulate[
 {Dynamic@a, Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}]},
 {a, 1, 4},
 {b, 0, 1, ControlType -> Slider, 
  Appearance -> Dynamic[If[a > 1, {Tiny}, {Large}]]}]
```

[image]

Now the same with a Manipulator (showing **it doesn't** work):

```
Manipulate[
 {Dynamic@a, Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}]},
 {a, 1, 4},
 {b, 0, 1, ControlType -> Manipulator, 
  Appearance -> Dynamic[If[a > 1, {Tiny}, {Large}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but the problem is that the Sliders don't have an "Open", "Closed" state and I am using Manipulators for that reason. I would like the users to be able to input a value directly.

Comment: @dabd I know. I'm trying to tell you that that isn't going to work easily

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, perhaps not as straightforward as might be hoped for but it works:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],

 {a, 1, 4},

 Row@List@With[{choice = Dynamic[If[a < 2, 1, 2]]},
    Overlay[{
      Control[{b, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Closed"}],
      Control[{b, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]},
     {choice}, choice]]]
```

Also take a look at the `ImageSize` settings for `Overlay`, if the switching has resizing issues.

**Edit** Oops. We can just do it this way:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],

 {a, 1, 4},

 Row@List@Dynamic[If[a < 2,
     Control[{b, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Closed"}],
     Control[{b, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]]]]
```

Comment: Very nice thanks!