# Can Manipulate parameters be hidden with an If statement?

Tags: manipulate, slider

I'm making a demonstration with the following code:

```
a = Pi/4;
b = 3 Pi/2;
f[x_, n_] = Piecewise[{{x + Sin[x] + n, x >= Pi}, {x + Sin[x], x < Pi}}];
Manipulate[
    Plot[
        f[x, n], {x, -Pi, 2 Pi + 1},
        PlotRange -> {{-1, 2 Pi + 1}, {-1, 2 Pi}},
        Epilog -> {
            Table[{Dotted, Line[{{-1, q}, {2 Pi + 1, q}}]}, {q, {f[a, n], f[b, n]}}],
            If[n == 0, {Dashed, Line[{{-1, f[c, n]}, {2 Pi + 1, f[c, n]}}]}, {Dashed, Line[{{-1, k}, {2 Pi + 1, k}}]}]
            },
        Ticks -> False,
        Axes -> False
        ],
    {{n, 0}, {0, Pi/2}},
    {{c, Pi}, a, b},
    {{k, f[a, n], "K"}, f[a, n], f[b, n]}
    ]
```

When `n=0` is selected, the `k` slider does nothing; when `n=Pi/2`, the `c` slider does nothing. Is there some way to hide the `k` and `c` sliders under the conditions for which they're inactive?

(Bonus points: For convenience, I'd like to post an animation of what happens for users who can't run it in Mathematica on their own, so if someone could post instructions or a link to where I can learn to make a screen-cap, I would greatly appreciate it!)

Comment: Once you set $n=0$ and the slider is hidden, how do you expect to then alter $n$ if you so wish?

Comment: I've restricted `n` so that it can only be toggled between `0` and `Pi/2`. My intention here is to demonstrate the Intermediate Value Theorem, which holds when using `f[x, 0]`, but not when using `f[x, Pi/2]`.

Comment: How about apply with `Enabled`  like`{{c, \[Pi]}, a, b, Enabled -> n == 0}`, `{{k, f[a, n], "K"}, f[a, n], f[b, n], Enabled -> n != 0}`

Comment: @JunhoLee I like your suggestion, though I was wondering if I could prevent the inactive parameter's slider from showing up at all.

Comment: You might find something to help you in this question and answer: [How to dynamically change the Appearance of a control in Manipulate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24580/27951)